# Use Less Qubits to simulate More Qubits

Tags: quantum-computing

Lots of (quantum) applications need thousands of qubits. But suppose we are short of stable qubits, is it possible (in general) using more time (or classical computation resources) to made up this shortage? Or is there any lower bound for this proving it can't be done?

Apology for phrasing the problem in just a few word, I just can't think of any technique for now.

Comment: Quantum computers can be simulated classically.

Comment: Of course it can, but it’s usually exponentially time consuming. What I ask is whether there’s a tight upper bound to do the simulation taking advantage of less qubits.

Comment: You wrote “using more time”...

Comment: I meant more than when you have more qubits, but simply setting qubits aside because they are not that much is kind of a waste.